# Problem with mapping two objects (with lists)

Tags: asp.net-core, mapping, mapper

I am looking for solution my issue... Probably my Shifts class cannot be mapped.

I have entity class Worker:

```
    public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string PhotoFilePath { get; set; }
    public Workplace Workplace { get; set; }
    public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public List<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Worker> ToList()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And model WorkerModel:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Imię")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Nazwisko")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Zdjęcie")]
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
    public string PhotoFilePath { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WorkplaceId { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceModel> Services { get; set; }
    public List<ShiftModel> Shifts { get; set; }
}
```

My default mapper profile:

```
            //Mapping workers
        CreateMap<Worker, WorkerModel>();
        CreateMap<WorkerModel, Worker>();
```

And when I try map model to entity class in my action:

```
        Worker worker = _mapper.Map<Worker>(model);
```

I get an issue:

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by different mapping types. Take the property `Service` as an example.

The resource is a type of `Service`.

[image]

But the destination is a type of `ServiceModel`.

[image]

So, they need to be converted. Here is a demo.

I create the `Service` and `ServiceModel` according to your model.

```
public class Service
{
    public int serviceID { get; set; }
    public string myservice { get; set; }
}
public class ServiceModel
{
    public int serviceID { get; set; }
    public string myservice { get; set; }
}
```

This is mapping relationship.

```
public class AutomapProfile : Profile
{
    public AutomapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Worker, WorkerModel>();
        CreateMap<WorkerModel, Worker>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Services, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Services.Select(a=>
            new Service
            {
                 serviceID=a.serviceID,
                  myservice=a.myservice
            })));
    }
}
```

This is the mapping method.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        var model = new WorkerModel
        {
            Id=1,
            Name="names",
            //...
            Services = new List<ServiceModel>
            {
                new ServiceModel{ serviceID=1, myservice="service1"},
                new ServiceModel{ serviceID=2, myservice="service2"},
            },
            //...
        };
        Worker worker = _mapper.Map<Worker>(model);
        return Ok(worker);
    }
```

Result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, I resolved that by: CreateMap<Shift, ShiftModel>(); CreateMap<ShiftModel, Shift>();

Comment: @Krispek , glad you can solve successfully. Could you click 'accept this answer'? Because this will encourage me to help solve more problem.